# use get_as_dataframe to read google_speadsheet

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I used get_as_dataframe to read google spreadsheets which is very similar to excel. column A are float numbers, the sum of column B, C and D.   A2 =B2+C2+D2. when I use 'get_as_dataframe' to read the spreadsheets as dataframe, the value of column A is not a float number but the str of the equation '=B2+C2+D2'.
how to fix this?
thanks

```
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
df = get_as_dataframe(sh.worksheet('sheetname'), parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
df = get_as_dataframe(sh.worksheet('sheetname'), parse_dates=True)
```

To:

```
df = get_as_dataframe(sh.worksheet('sheetname'), parse_dates=True, evaluate_formulas=True)
```

- It seems that `evaluate_formulas` is `False` as the default value. In this case, `valueRenderOption` uses `'FORMULA'` at [`'valueRenderOption': ('UNFORMATTED_VALUE' if evaluate_formulas else 'FORMULA'),`](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe/blob/80cf07fc147909a356712d08e6e80ee6a2c0e9f4/gspread_dataframe.py#L83). By this, the formulas are retrieved. When `evaluate_formulas=True` is used, the number values can be retrieved instead of the formulas.

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### References:

- [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @hellokitty Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.